# CrudRepository doesn't provide a way of checking whether saveall method got commited

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

I'm using CrudRepository's saveAll method of spring framework.

```
validationRowRepository.saveAll(validationRows);
```

Now I got such requirment of only doing the next step, when we are ensured that current batch is persisted into database and transaction is committed.

By looking at the saveAll method specification, I decided to go this way of checking that.

```
    List<ValidationRow> savedRows = (List<ValidationRow>) validationRowRepository.saveAll(validationRows);
    if (Objects.equals(savedRows.size(), validationRows.size()) {
        // do the next step.
    }
```

Even if this is true, so what's gonna happen if the execution won't enter the if block ?
So my question is:
Is there a more propper way of implementing this kind of scenario.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API, but I _assume_ that if anything went wrong then an exception would have been thrown.

Comment: Have you found answer for your question?

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to consider:

1. writing data to the database
2. committing the transaction

The contract of `saveAll` is as follows:

All entities will be written to the database. If this doesn't work for at least one of the entities an exception will be thrown. The return value of `saveAll` will have always the same size as the input value. It will not contain `null` values. All contained entities will have their id value set (not `null` for object type, not `0` for primitive numeric types)

Therefore your if-condition is superfluous and tests for a very specific bug in Spring Data JDBC. What would make sense is to have a test, as an actual JUnit test, that your entity can get loaded after saving and looks as inspected. This would basically be a test of the consistency of your object model, the database schema, the mapping and the logic implemented in Spring Data JDBC. There are lot of things that might go wrong. Good to have a test for that.

Your code doesn't even touch the topic of transactions. There are two major ways to control transactions:

1. [`@Transactional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html)
2. [`TransactionTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html)

Both build on the Spring transaction infrastructure which guarantees to throw an exception if a transaction fails to commit. Similar to what I wrote above it might make sense to write a test, i.e. a JUnit test that checks that the transaction behaves as desired. Although this might be difficult because you'll have to inject some kind of database failure to do that.

So all that's left for your actual code is to handle any exception that might get thrown in a call to `saveAll`. Since the transaction boundaries are easier to move using a `TransactionTemplate` I use it in the example code.

```java
try {
    validationRows = txTemplate.execute( t -> validationRowRepository.saveAll(validationRows));
    process(validationRows) // do whatever you want to do with the entities after saving
} catch (DataAccessException e) {
    // do whatever you see fit in the case of an exception. You might also skip the try catch block and just let the exception terminate the process, or in case of a web application the request.
}
```

Comment: Jens Schauder that piece of code I pasted here is in a method, which is anotated as @Transactional, I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `saveAll`, data have to become saved. In other case an exception will have to be thrown and then you will can to handle possible exception. Code which you've written is correctly and you really don't need to do fancy security. ;)